# Subscribe to Observable -> Filter -> Provide as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to work out an Angular service that consumes other services to provide meta data on those services. The data objects are different classes of people with a connecting class. (i.e. Client, Consultant, and sales relationship.)

A basic metric I would like to track is whether the client has been assigned a consultant. (i.e. un-matched). I have in my standard service, an Observable Array called Clients that I subscribe to in my MetaData Service like so:

```
this.clientService.clientArray().map( ..... ).subscribe(i => this.unmatchedClients.next(i);
```

What I want to do is filter the array that comes in from the Observable Subscription to check multiple fields. It was suggested elsewhere that I should have the full filter call like this:

```
this.clientService.clientArray().map( r => {
    r.filter( i => {
        i.connected === true
    })
}).subscribe(r => this.unmatchedClients.next(r));
```

The expected results should be an array  of clients, not individual clients which I can subscribe to and get the length for counting.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does filtering in the map not work for you? BTW in that code you should have a `return` before the `r.filter(...)` since it is surrounded by `{}`'s.

Comment: It hasn't, but I think it's because I didn't fully understand observables

Comment: Try adding the return statement. If that doesn't work can you give an example of the data that is returned by `this.clientService.clientArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one additional unnecessary step. If you want to filter the array you pipe to the subscription why not just do

```
this.clientService.clientArray()
 .filter( client => {
    return client.connected;
})
.subscribe(r => this.unmatchedClients.next(r));
```

The bit of code inside the subscription I have no idea what’s the goal so I kept it as is.